# Set jQuery toggle type as variable

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Is there a way to set the toggle type as a variable? I have a function that fires the below markup; but sometimes I need it to be 'slideToggle' instead of 'fadeToggle'. I can easily set this as a conditional; but then I have to repeat markup.

Obviously the below code does not work; but it shows kind of what I'm going for.

```
var toggleType = ( _settings.toggleType == 'fade' ? 'fadeToggle' : 'slideToggle'  );

jQuery(_settings.target).stop(true, true).toggleType(function(){
    // callback after animation completes
});
```

---

Jason P led me to a working solution.

```
// set toggle type
var toggleType = ( _settings.toggleType == 'fade' ? 'fadeToggle' : 'slideToggle'  );

// toggle action
jQuery(_settings.target).stop(true, true)[toggleType](function(){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
jQuery(_settings.target).stop(true, true)[toggleType](function(){
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had to use this to get it to work. Having the quotes around toggleType caused an error. Just using the variable name worked though. 

jQuery(_settings.target).stop(true, true)[toggleType](function(){

Comment: @GregT Edited. That dot shouldn't have been there.